# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_24 to have shape (256, 256, 1) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)

Tags: python, keras, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I'm applying UNET biomedical segmentation network on colored image data and Ground truth of 50 images (converted into NPY file of size 50,256,256,3 each), but getting above error and network is unable to jump into training. The model summary is given below:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 256, 256, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 64) 1792        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 64) 36928       conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 128 73856       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 128 147584      conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 256)  590080      conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 256)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 512)  1180160     max_pooling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 512)  2359808     conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 32, 32, 512)  0           conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 16, 16, 512)  0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 16, 16, 1024) 4719616     max_pooling2d_4[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 1024) 9438208     conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 16, 16, 1024) 0           conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 1024) 0           dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 512)  2097664     up_sampling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 32, 32, 1024) 0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
                                                                 conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 512)  4719104     concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 512)  2359808     conv2d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 512)  0           conv2d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 256)  524544      up_sampling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 64, 64, 512)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
                                                                 conv2d_14[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 256)  1179904     concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 256)  590080      conv2d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 256 0           conv2d_16[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 131200      up_sampling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 128, 128, 256 0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
                                                                 conv2d_17[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 295040      concatenate_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 147584      conv2d_18[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_4 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 256, 256, 128 0           conv2d_19[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 32832       up_sampling2d_4[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)     (None, 256, 256, 128 0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
                                                                 conv2d_20[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 73792       concatenate_4[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_22 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 36928       conv2d_21[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 2)  1154        conv2d_22[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_24 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 1)  3           conv2d_23[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 31,032,837
Trainable params: 31,032,837
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

also model architecture is as follows:

```
import numpy as np 
import os
import skimage.io as io
import skimage.transform as trans
import numpy as np
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from keras import backend as keras


def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,3)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    #model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_24 to have shape (256, 256, 1) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you print the shapes of your label data (`train_y`)? Looks like your `train_y` has shape `(256,256,3)` but your network's output has the shape `(256,256,1)`.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. Something's wrong with the data you're feeding into. Check dimensions

Comment: @anishmm Got me thanks for help ..... need to change output shape

Comment: Final layer must have dimension equal to number of classes. One hot encoding of classes is required https://stackoverflow.com/a/55992428/9524424