# Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (20,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I'm writing a CNN classifier for 20 classes. As mentioned in the title, this is the error i get when i try to `fit` my model.

I've already checked this answer: [Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392972/error-when-checking-target-expected-dense-3-to-have-shape-3-but-got-array-wi/55992428), but i have already (i think) set the `categorical` conversion.

Here's my code:

1) Imagegenerator:

```
apply_data_augmentation = True

if apply_data_augmentation:
   train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10,    #Training data generator + validation split (20%)
                                      width_shift_range=10,
                                      height_shift_range=10,
                                      zoom_range=0.3,
                                      horizontal_flip=True,
                                      vertical_flip=True,
                                      fill_mode='constant',
                                      cval=0,
                                      rescale=1./255,
                                      validation_split=0.2)
else:
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

2) Getting data:

```
dataset_dir = os.path.join(cwd, 'Classification_Dataset')

bs = 8

# img shape
img_h = 28
img_w = 28

 num_classes=20

 decide_class_indices = False
 if decide_class_indices:
    classes = ['airplane',       # 0
               'bear',           # 1
               'calculator',    # 2
               'computer-monitor',              # 3
               'fireworks',          # 4
               'galaxy',          # 5
               'grand-piano',   # 6
               'kangaroo',             # 7
               'laptop',            # 8
               'lightbulb',         # 9
               'lightning',             # 10
               'mountain-bike',       # 11
               'owl',  # 12
               'school-bus',     # 13
               'sheet-music',           # 14
               'skyscraper',         # 15
               'sword',              # 16
               't-shirt',             # 17
               'waterfall',  # 18
               'wine-bottle']        # 19
else:
    classes=None
print(classes)
# Training
training_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'training')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    training_dir,
    target_size=(img_h, img_w),
    batch_size=bs,
    class_mode='categorical',
    classes=classes,
    subset='training',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=SEED) # set as training data

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    training_dir, # same directory as training data
    target_size=(img_h, img_w),
    batch_size=bs,
    class_mode='categorical',
    classes=classes,
    subset='validation',
    shuffle=False,
    seed=SEED) # set as validation data

print(train_generator)
```

3) Model + fit:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, AveragePooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,3)))
model.add(AveragePooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units=120, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(units=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(units=20, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])



nb_epochs = 5
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // bs,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // bs,
    epochs = nb_epochs)
```

I checked all the possible problems mentioned in many questions (such as missing flatten layers, categorical conversion, non matching inputs, ) but (at least to me) everything seems fine. 
I can't understand where's the problem.

Comment: You should use "categorical_crossentropy" as your loss function while compiling your model since you are are expecting one hot encoded label.

Comment: It worked! You can answer the question so I can accept your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `flow_from_directory` function with `class_mode='categorical'` generates one-hot encoded 2D labels ([Ref](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)) whereas `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` expects integer value. 
You have two ways to fix the issue:
1. Change the loss function to `categorical_crossentropy` when you compile your model
2. Change the label to `sparse` mode by using `class_mode='sparse'` in the `flow_from_directory` function

In a nutshell, when your label is an integer value (representing class) use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and when label is one-hot encoded use `categorical_crossentropy` as loss function.