# How to merge four binary keras models into one (same input, but 4 different output)

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to create a "Text" Classifier. I have a labelled dataset with values such as "Spam", "Racism", "Sexual", "Insult" etc.

I have `2 million labelled examples of Insult category`
`30K labelled examples of Sexual category`
`20K Labelled examples of Racism category`
`50k labelled examples of Spam category`

I have created this model (binary):

```
inp1 = Input(shape=(max_len,))
e1 = Embedding(max_features+1, dim, weights=[glove_matrix],trainable = False,)(inp1)
x = CuDNNLSTM(max_len)(e1)
x = Dense(100, activation="relu",)(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))(x)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('spamModelv1.h5' , monitor='val_acc', save_best_only = True, mode ='auto')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint,EarlyStopping(patience=10,monitor='val_acc')]

model.fit(x_train,y_train, 
                      batch_size=128, 
                      validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                      epochs=1000,
                      callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Currently, I have 4 different models for 4 different categories. This is decreasing the model inference speed. How can I merge them?

Off topic: If you can improve my LSTM model architecture to improve accuracy, or give me link to more spam, racism & sexual detection dataset, that would be great.

Comment: Should be easy, encode classes as one hot, change the output layer (capacity equal to classes), adjust the loss to categorical crossenthropy https://stackoverflow.com/a/55992428/9524424

Comment: I have around 2.2 million rows, but have label of toxicity for only 2 million, spam for only 50k etc....So what should be the value of spam for the other rows?

Comment: In the case of spam: if spam = true ==1, else = 0, just as posted in the link. Its a one hot encoded matrix, indicating if a label is true (1) or not (0)

Comment: I mean. Let's say, I have 2.2 million training rows. I have 50k rows labelled as "spam" or "not spam". The other 2.15 million rows are labelled nothing. They can be spam or not spam...I don't know the label

Comment: Sorry, I failed to explain it. I realized that now.