# Changing Keras Model from Binary Classification to Multi-classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, data-science

I have the following model

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=unitsNumber, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(61,1)))
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding1D(padding=1))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=unitsNumber, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())  # now output shape == (None, 1160)
model.add(layers.Dense(unitsNumber, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  #sortie binaire
model.summary()
```

which is giving me this summary

```
Model: "sequential_8"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_15 (Conv1D)           (None, 59, 40)            160       
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding1d_8 (ZeroPaddin (None, 61, 40)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_16 (Conv1D)           (None, 59, 40)            4840      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_8 (MaxPooling1 (None, 29, 40)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_8 (Flatten)          (None, 1160)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 40)                46440     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 41        
=================================================================
Total params: 51,481
Trainable params: 51,481
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And I use this classifier

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Which gives me a good accuracy of 87%, with the target variable being one of two groups.

However, I want to change my dataset and create more groups of the same data, instead of just having the two.

So instead of trying to predict the output of 1 or 0, the output could be any one number of values between 0 and say 8 (9 groups in total).

I do plan on changing the amount of groups to give a trade-off of accuracy vs group size, as the more number of the groups there are, it will be harder to classify.

I have tried the following classifiers

`model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc']) model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc']) model.compile(optimizer='Nadam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])`

But I get the following error:

```
UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
 [[{{node conv1d_7/convolution/Conv2D}}]]
 [[{{node metrics_3/acc/Mean_1}}]]
```

I am not certain what the problem is, but I believe I may be using the wrong type of model for a multi-classification problem. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.
Thanks

UPDATE: SHOW HOW DATA IS BEING SHAPED:

```
# Initial Format
X_train.shape


# Shape data for CNN
X_train_values = X_train.values
y_train_values = y_train.values
X_train_values = 
X_train_values.reshape 
((X_train_values.shape[0],X_train_values.shape[1],1))
X_train_values.shape

X_test_values = X_test.values
y_test_values = y_test.values
X_test_values = 
X_test_values.reshape((X_test_values.shape[0],X_test_values.shape[1],1))

unitsNumber = 40
```

Comment: Ok, I do not understand how your data is being shaped, and both current answers are different depending on this and could lead you to catastrophical results. Which one looks like your `y`: 1. `[0,1,0,0,1]`; 2. `[[0,3], [0,5], [5,1]]` 3. `[[1,1,1], [1,0,0], [1,1,0]]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your final layer activation function to 'softmax'.
The number of nodes in your final layer should be equal to the number of classes you'd like to predict. (9 in your case).

```
model.add(layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax'))
```

Loss function should be 'categorical_crossentroy'

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: I tried this but got the following error `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (9,) but got array with shape (1,)`

Comment: I will update the question to show how the data is being shaped

Comment: Please also specify which one of your layers is dense_4 (as you have 2 dense layers). A summary of your model after you modified it would be even better :)

Comment: Sorry I dont fully understand what you're asking for.. you mean like a summary I have originally?

Comment: I'll just write it down here. The problem is with the shape of your labelled data. you can solve it in one of the two solutions I suggest: 1. change the loss function to 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' instead of 'categorical_crossentropy' which allows you some flexibility with the y variable shape. 2. reshape your labelled variable so it's shape will fit the amount of classes you'd like to predict. You can find more information on this topic in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392972/error-when-checking-target-expected-dense-3-to-have-shape-3-but-got-array-wi

Comment: OK it was the final dense layer that was dense_4, sorry the numbers changed when I re-executed the cells so I couldnt see at first

Comment: Now I get the following error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (61, 9) but got array with shape (61, 1)`

Comment: So I believe yes its to do with the shaping of the data, but I do not know at which point I reshape to allow for the 9 y target variables?

Comment: I changed this line `model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=unitsNumber, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(61,1)))` to this `model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=unitsNumber, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(61,9)))`

Comment: But I reverted to the original and now I am back to the exact same error as in the beginning

Comment: Tried to keep the original code with the new loss function but there is no change :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217847/discussion-between-my-koryto-and-sdrob).

Answer (score 1):

#### Last dense layer activation

1. If you have two classes (binary classification) you should use `sigmoid` activation
2. If it is multi class you should use `softmax` activation

#### Loss function

1. If your labels are one hot encoded then you should use `categorical_crossentropy`
2. If your labels are encoded as numbers (0 to n-1 for n class classification) then you should use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

#### Samples

```
def create_model():
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(61,1)))
    model.add(keras.layers.ZeroPadding1D(padding=1))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())  # now output shape == (None, 1160)
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax'))  #sortie binaire
    return model

# One-Hot-encoding
X = np.random.rand(100,61,1)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100,9))
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(X, y)

# Class encoded as a number
X = np.random.rand(100,61,1)
y = np.random.randint(0, 9, (100,1))
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Binary classification or logistic regression problem is used to output 0 or 1 (Positive or negative, cat or dog, etc,.). This is dependent on the dataset labels. For this kind of problem you use crossentropy loss and sigmoid activation in the output layer with only 1 neuron.
2. On the other hand, For a multiclass classification problem softmax is used in the output layer with Dense layer number = number of classes in the dataset. categorical or sparse crossentropy is used depending on the labels.